# 100% width dropdown with CSS triangle relative to parent item

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with some items displaying a drop down on rollover.

What I want to achieve:

- Dropdown to be inside the parent element to use the :hover pseudo class to display it
- Dropdown is 100% of the window width, not it's parent
- Dropdown's contents to not be positioned relative to the parent menu item
- CSS triangle to point to the middle of the parent menu item
- CSS transition to fade the menu in and move it down into position

Quick fiddle of the type of layout I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/kn3Z3/2/

As I want to keep the dropdown INSIDE the parent element, I set the parent element's `position: static`.  The issue is now I have no reference to position the CSS triangle to.

I can't hard code the dropdown's position for each menu item because

1. the menu will be dynamic, and
2. The font size of the menu bar changes with media-queries (in the fiddle, I also made them change color to easily see that happening)

I tried other solutions where the triangle was part of the parent menu item itself.  This meant I couldn't get it animating as one with the menu correctly - and the performance of the animation was worse.

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this or am I right in thinking this approach with the animation isn't possible?

*PS: Also tried the 100% width solution described in here: [Dropdown Menu - Make the <ul> submenu 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370759/dropdown-menu-make-the-ul-submenu-100-width) but I need the dropdown's contents to not be relatively aligned to the parent menu item.*

Answer (score 2):

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.nav div {
  padding: 6.25px 12.5px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}
.item:hover:before {
  content: "";
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.item:hover .subnav {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.subnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  opacity: 1;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out, transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```