# Dropdown menu <ul> 100% width, inline sub menu items

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I found this SO discussion ([Dropdown Menu - Make the <ul> submenu 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370759/dropdown-menu-make-the-ul-submenu-100-width)) which comes incredibly close to what I am looking for, but the sub menu items are stacked. I want to have the sub menu items inline, not stacked. I have tried floating, inline-block on the sub menu but nothing gets them inline.

Comment: Can you please post your last attempt?  A Codepen or JSFiddle would also be handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that example, the max width of the sub menu items is limited by the container's width. You can make them to stay inline as below:

```
.nav > ul > li > ul {
    ...
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbLrW/288/)**

```css
/* not very relevant styling */
h1         { font-size: 20px; padding-top: 20px; }
.container { position: relative; margin: 20px auto 0 auto; width: 75%; }
.header    { background: #eee; }
.nav       { background: #ccc; }


/* relevant styling */

body { overflow-x: hidden; } /* trick from css-tricks comments */

/* FIRST LEVEL */

.nav > ul > li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

/* SECOND LEVEL */

.nav > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 0 1000em; /* trick from css-tricks comments */
    margin: 0 -1000em; /* trick from css-tricks comments */
    z-index: 101;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 240, 240, 0.8);
    white-space: nowrap; /*new*/
}

.nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    padding: 3px 0;
    display: inline-block; /*new*/
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hank's Big Leauge Widgets</h1>
        <span>You want a widget? we got 'em!</span>
    </div>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION -->    
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="container">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Widget A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Widget B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Widget C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Locations</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Location A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Location B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Location C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Staff</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">President</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manager</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="content container">
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do it:

1. **Flexbox** - the submenu `ul` should have the following CSS:

   ul {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content: space-between;
   }

[More info on flexbox on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

2. **Inline** - The `li` children of the submenu `ul` should have `display: inline;`

From the nature of the solution in the link you provided, both ways need the submenu ul to have a fixed width.